# H2 Database runs sql scripts multiple time

Tags: sql, h2, spring-test, jdbctemplate

I use the h2 database for repository unit testing , ı run the test cases as a class then scripts run multiple time. if i run the as one function then run normnally.

I am doing unit testing to repository layer of my spring project that was developed jdbctemplate.
But I have a problem that ı run the test cases with class then i observed the scripts run multiple time however if i run the the test case only one function then these scripts runs once.

```
@JdbcTest
@Sql(scripts = {"sqlFiles/A.sql", "sqlFiles/B.sql", "sqlFiles/C.sql", "sqlFiles/D.sql"})
class RepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    Repository repository;
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        repository = new Repository ();
        repository.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void findAll() {
        var result = repository.findAll();
        //one data was added for test
        assertEquals(1, result.size());
        assertEquals("OID_1", result.get(0).getOid());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Seems to be an issue of the Spring data source. The typìcal workaround is to add `drop table if exists my_table;` for each table at the beginning of each script. Not great, but it's not H2; it's Spring.

Comment: Actually, i want to find real solution ,otherwise i can do that ı put the TRUNCATE TABLE table name on the top of insertion operations in my sql script but as i said i want to find real solution. thanks for advice.

Comment: I think you need to look into Spring's documentation. The key point is to prevent the data source to open more than a single connection to the database. Maybe the connection pool size should be limited to a max of 1 connection. In any case, this is not a problem in H2, but in Spring.